# use of static array to initialize constant struct object

Tags: c, linux, networking

I recently came across the following code:

```
    static const struct gaih gaih[] = {    
#if defined __UCLIBC_HAS_IPV6__    
    { PF_INET6, gaih_inet },    
#endif    
    { PF_INET, gaih_inet },    
#if 0   
    { PF_LOCAL, gaih_local },    
#endif    
    { PF_UNSPEC, NULL }    
};    



     struct gaih {    
            int family;    
            int (*gaih)(const char *name, const struct gaih_service *service,    
                    const struct addrinfo *req, struct addrinfo **pai);    
        };    


int func{    

const struct gaih *g = gaih;    

    }
```

I understand the meaning of constant and static .
But I able to decipher the logic behind static initialization of the constant object in such a crude way.
please clarify the reason or use of doing it this way

Comment: What language is this?  If this is C or C++ you should use the correct syntax.

Comment: It is C code used to get address of  a host in network

Comment: This isn't legal code. Show us the correct code.

Comment: This is part of a working project. I think to illustrate my question about initializing constant struct object with a static array this code portion  will suffice.

Comment: If you want to discus details of a language you should provide syntactic correct code. Even if it is just an example. It is otherwise hart to distinguish between simplification and real syntactic error. E.g. the declaration of the struct needs no `=`.

Comment: Provided the actual working piece :D

Comment: Don't add unrealtred tags. This is not releated to embedded devices.

Comment: The line: `int func{` is not legal C.  I guess this is supposed to be a function, but a function needs `int func(void){` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.c` seems to be a C file. Using `static` in C has two meanings:

1. Not on the stack (e.g. for variables inside functions that shall keep their value across several calls of the function)
2. Not exported from this module (for variables that shall not be provided as a symbol to the linker)

In this case it seems to be the second one. The variable `gaih` shall not be exported (visible for the linker) `static` and it shall not be changed `const`. There is nothing crude.

But to clarify further details the complete valid code would be needed. It seems to be a constant and static initialisation of an array of structs with just one entry. The variable `g` is just a pointer to this single entry.

This example has some similarity with the `struct gaih_addrtuple` in `nss.h` which is a linked list of host names and IP addresses used for `gethostbyname`.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `gaih` is defined as `static`, which means it is only visible in the current file, and `const`, which means it can't be modified once initialized.

The local variable `g` is also defined as `const`, meaning it can't be changed.  It is initialized with the address of the global `gaih` array, so `g` can be treated as an array in this context.

`g` can also be passed to another function, possibly in a different file.  This allows the contents of `gaih` to be read outside of the current file which would not be allowed by attempting to reference `gaih` directly.

Comment: What is `int func{ const struct gaih *g = gaih;  }` ?   It is certainly not a function...  Would it not need at least `int func(void){...return 0; }` to make it compile in C?